# How to build a docker image that can copy a file from a host to container in mac os?

Tags: macos, docker

I have a docker installed in my mac. And I am trying to write a `Dockerfile` that can copy from a macos file path to the container. I tried both `ADD` and `COPY` as listed in the docs but they don't work on macos.

I see that docker on mac installed linux kernel so the host would be the linux running inside a mac I suppose but my file is in a mac file system therefore it doesn't work.

How do I get around this?

Comment: `they don't work on macos.` can you provide error message? Because these command work on macos, the issue is probably in your particular config

Comment: failed to compute cache key `/home/john/bin` not found: not found.

Comment: I have a file located in `/home/john/bin/foo.py` in my mac os file system